# DT unit impulse function properties proof

Tags: homework, proof

How to prove the following properties of DT unit impulse function. If anyone got link to a proof please mention it. I have search on the web. But only found the properties, not a proper method of proof.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: The expressions look like steps (1) and (2) to prove (3): that the impulse is the neutral of the convolution. It doesn't seem to be 3 independent "properties" that need a proof. Please include the original problem statement and your progress so far.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :
Use definition of $\sigma[n]$

consider
 2 cases
$$m=n$$
$$m\ne n$$

also, use definition of convolution

as an aside, it took me a while to do this but a good habit is to use $[n]$ (square brackets) for discrete time index, and $(t)$ (curved brackets) for continuous time

Answer (score 0):

Remember the discrete delta function:

$$
\begin{equation}
\delta[n] = 1,n=0 \\
   \hspace{1.5cm} =0, otherwise
\end{equation}
$$

The following is valid, because if $m\neq n$ both the sides evaluate to $0$
$$x[m]\delta[n-m] = x[n]\delta[n-m]$$

Extending the logic to convolution, when you have $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n]\delta[m-n]$, all terms except for $m=n$ vanish because of the delta function. So you will be left with $x[m]$